# Draw star shape using a class?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have to draw a star shape using a Python class; this is a homework problem.

```
from tkinter import*

class star:
    def _init_(self, w, h):
        root=Tk()
        root.title("Mercy Cybersecurity HWb")
        self.canvas=Canvas(root, bg="#1199ff", width=w, height=h)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.draw(w,h)

    def draw(self,w,h):

        for i in range(0,2):
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(20+i*10, 30+i*10, w-20-i*20, h-30-i*20)
        #root.mainloop()

star(700,400)
```

I have several problems

- 1st error is that Object() takes no parameters for line star(700, 400).
- 2nd error is that when I try to draw the polygon, it does not work.
  canv.create_polygon(10,40,40,40,50,10,60,40,90,40,65,60,75,90,50,70,25,90,35,60, fill="#ff0000",)

Where do I have to put this line for star shape ?

- Another problem is how can I display the star shape in the middle of a rectangle?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.  Most of all, please restrict yourself to one question per posting.  Don't post those later questions until you've actually tried to do it yourself.  Since you haven't been able to run this code, you don't yet *know* what the program will do with that call to **create_polygon**.

Comment: For #1, your `_init_()` should be named `__init__()`—in other words it must have _two_ leading and trailing underscore characters.

Comment: `create_polygon(x+10, y+40, x+40, y+40, x+50, y+10, ...)` or better move to `(0,0)` -> `create_polygon(x+0, y+30, x+30, y+30, x+40, y+0, ...)` and then you have to set correct `x,y` before you draw it. Star has size about 80 height and 80 width so `x = w/2 - 80/2, y = h/2 - 80/2`

Answer (score 3):

I changed your code so you get some output (I only made a triangle, change that to a star yourself).

```
from Tkinter import*

class star:
    def __init__(self, w, h):
        self.root=Tk()
        self.root.title("Mercy Cybersecurity HWb")
        self.canvas=Canvas(self.root, bg="#1199ff", width=w, height=h)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.draw(w,h)

def draw(self,w,h):
    for i in range(0,2):
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(20+i*10, 30+i*10, w-20-i*20, h-30-i*20)
    self.canvas.create_polygon(100, 100, 300, 300, 400, 200)
    self.root.mainloop()

star(700,400)
```

Your errors were:

1. `__init__` was misspelled.
2. You forgot `self.` in front of `root` to make it visible in the whole class.
3. You forgot to draw the star shape, in this example, I drew the triangle. with `self.canvas.create_polygon(100, 100, 300, 300, 400, 200)`.

Comment: Hello Alex, Thank you so much for your help. But I didt get any output for self.canvas.create_polygon(100, 100, 300, 300, 400, 200). Could you please check the code for polygon then I'll code for star shape like self.canvas.create_polygon(10, 40, 40, 40, 50, 10, 60, 40, 90, 40, 65, 60, 75, 90, 50, 70, 25, 90, 35, 60). PLease add fill color for polygon....

How I can I display the star shape center of the rectangle ? Please ..

Comment: I get the star shape, in the upper left corner of the canvas. For the center issus, calculate the center of your shape, the center of the rectangle and add/subtact the difference into the respective X- and Y-Coordinates of the shape.

Answer (score 2):

The constructor is __init__ (double underscores); you used _init_ (single underscores).  Thus, you inherited the default constructor, which takes no arguments.  When I made that change, the initialization went through just fine.